# Having trouble drawing Minesweeper game board

Tags: c++, data-structures, minesweeper

I am working on building a Minesweeper game using C++. Right now I am lost trying to read in an input file and use the contents to build my game board to look like this:
[GameBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7LSu.png)

This is what I have so far:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "UI.hpp"
#include "drawboard.hpp"

int main()
{

    UI start;
    start.Gameprompt();        

    int drawgame[4][4] = {{' ',' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' ',' '}};
    drawBoard(drawgame);


    return 0;
}
```

**UI.hpp**

```
#ifndef UI_HPP
#define UI_HPP


#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class UI
{

    private:
            std::string filename;


    public:
            void GamePrompt();


};


#endif
```

**UI.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


#include "UI.hpp"


void UI::GamePrompt()
{
    std::ifstream inFS;

    while (!inFS.is_open())
    {
            std::cout << "Please enter a file name with the minefield information: " << std::endl;
            std::cin >> filename;
            inFS.open(filename.c_str());
    }


}
```

**drawboard.hpp**

```
#ifndef DRAWBOARD_HPP
#define DRAWBOARD_HPP

class drawBoard
{

    private:
            int board[4][4];

    public:
            drawBoard(int board[][4]);


};

#endif
```

**drawboard.cpp**

```
#include "drawboard.hpp"
#include<iostream>

drawBoard::drawBoard(int board[][4])
{

    std::cout << " 0 1 2 3 " << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {

            std::cout << " +---+---+---+---+" << std::endl;
            std::cout << i + 1;

            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {

                    std::cout << " | " << board[i][j];

            }

            std::cout << " | " << std::endl;

    }

    std::cout << " +---+---+---+---+" << std::endl;

}
```

These are the errors that I am receiving right now:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:18:20: error: conflicting declaration ‘drawBoard drawgame’
drawBoard(drawgame);
                ^
main.cpp:16:6: error: ‘drawgame’ has a previous declaration as ‘int drawgame [4][4]’
int drawgame[4][4] = {{' ',' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' ',' '}};
  ^
main.cpp:16:6: warning: unused variable ‘drawgame’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: `Gameprompt` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is actually kind of obscure...

When the compiler sees the line

```
drawBoard(drawgame);
```

it thinks you're defining the variable `drawgame` as a `drawBoard` instance, i.e. what it thinks is that you're doing

```
drawBoard drawgame;
```

The solution is simple, define the variable like you normally would, and then pass the array to the constructor, as in

```
drawBoard board(drawgame);
```

---

Or as mentioned in a comment you could do

```
drawBoard{drawgame};
```

But this only creates a *temporary* `drawBoard` object that will be destructed immediately.

Comment: You also could call the constructor with `drawBoard{drawgame}`; if the variable `board` is not needed.